# Suppose $y$, Does $\frac{dy}{dy} $ have meaning when we derive it with respect to itself?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have a function and want to derive it with respect to itself e.g: $$\frac{dy}{dy} $$

Does this have any meaning , and if so what will be it's value?

Comment: The answer is just 1!

Comment: or zero perhaps?

Comment: No, definitely 1

Comment: This doesn't have meaning.

Comment: @GitGud No, it's 1

Comment: @columbus8myhw: in what theory and under what definition of the derivative would that have a meaning?

Comment: @AlexandreHalm The same theory in which $dy/dx$ or $dx/dx$ do.

Comment: [Related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466419/differentiating-one-function-with-respect-to-another).

Comment: Just curious, but any particular reason for the rollback of my edit? (However, if you do not wish to explain, please feel free to ignore this comment.)

Comment: I didnt really see any improvement and besides I already rejected that very same edit a day ago. please don't be offended.

Comment: @Bak1139 I downvoted your question for having poor wording (in English, we "differentiate" functions, not "derive" them), inadequate capitalization, and an unclear title. Perhaps you would be inclined to make some changes to the question not entirely unlike those that J W made before you rolled them back.

Comment: @Bak1139: Don't worry, I'm not offended at all. (Life's too short.) That said, you might wish to note senshin's comment.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We are basically asking what is the rate by which $y$ changes with respect to $y$? Since $y$ changes proportionately to itself, the value is $1$.

Notice that you probably do this implicitly if you have differentiated some functions before. For instance, if $y=2x$, then $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(2x)=2.$ That is, the rate by which $y$ changes with respect to $x$ is $2$, since every time $y$ increases or decreases by $2$, $x$ only increases or decreases by $1$. Now suppose instead that $y=x$, since $y$ is changing only as much as $x$ is, the rate by which $y$ changes with respect to $x$ is now $1$. Thus, $\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}(y)=\frac{d}{dx}(x)=1$.

Comment: Possibly wrong if dy is zero (y is a constant). I am not sure what the most useful and appropriate definition to give dy/dy when y is constant is though.

Comment: If $y$ is meant to be a variable, how can it be constant? It would be of no use in differentiation.

Comment: Basically writing $\frac{dx}{dx}$ is an abuse of notation. When writing $\frac{dx}{dx}$ what you actually mean is $\frac{df}{dx}$ when $f=\text{identity}$, *i.e.*, $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @hjhjhj57 If you want to take this stance, then even writing $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is an abuse of notation, because it is nowhere indicated that $y$ is a function of $x$. The most "correct" way would be if you indicate that $D$ is an operator on functions, i.e. something like $D[(x\in\Bbb R\mapsto x)]=(x\in\Bbb R\mapsto 1)$, but needless to say this notation isn't likely to catch on anytime soon.

Answer (score 18):

Define the function $f(y)=y$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;$ (1)

We will use the first principle here,

Let a small increment in $y$ correspond to $f(y+\Delta y)$

Then , $f(y+\Delta y)=y+\Delta y$ $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$ (2)

Subtract (1) from (2)

$f(y+\Delta y)-f(y)=\Delta y$

Re-arranging.

$\frac{f(y+\Delta y)-f(y)}{\Delta y}=1$

Taking limit $\Delta y\to 0$

$\frac{d[f(y)]}{dy}=1=\frac{d(y)}{dy}$

Hence, essentially you are measuring the rate of change of quantity with respect to itself. It's quite easy to see why it makes sense.

Comment: Plus 1 for first principles

Comment: What if y is a constant and so Δy equals zero?

Comment: If $y$ is constant, then you have a difficulty defining $d(\mbox{anything})/dy$. Every derivative has this problem; it is nothing special about $dy/dy$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , example y=y, dy/dy=1 , means that y is equal to its own coordinate and its rate of change is 1

Comment: what does this mean in the context of the problem??

Comment: Ignore it misread question

Comment: @talmudist You can delete answers, אחי.

Comment: How can I delete answer ? No option for it

Comment: @talmudist underneath the text of your post, you should see text links that say 'share' 'edit' 'delete' 'flag'

Comment: I only have "edit", " share", "more" if I click more I get "flag" only

Comment: What if y is a constant and so Δy equals zero?

Comment: Yes rate doesn't change stays 0 with constant function

Comment: Depends how you define the function

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac d{dy}$$
means differentiation with respect to $y$. Thus,
$$\frac{dy}{dy}$$
is differentiating $y$ with respect to $y$. The derivative of $y$ with respect to $y$ is $\boxed1$. (It's slightly easier to understand if you replace all of the $y$s with $x$ — we're more used to differentiating with respect to $x$ than with respect to $y$.)

Comment: What if y is a constant and so Δy equals zero?

Comment: @StevenStewart-Gallus You could say the same thing to $\frac{dy}{dx}$. What if $x$ is constant?

Comment: I agree with colombus: Why would one ever differentiate anything, constant or otherwise, with respect to a constant? Objection overruled.

Answer (score 0):

dy/dy is 1 unless possibly y is a constant or has constant portions. However, this statement seems kind of meaningless. What is y a constant in respect to?

One possible way to solve the problem might be to formulate everything as varying according to a single global time parameter t. Then dy/dy is better described as dyₜ/dyₜ and by the chain rule is dyₜ/dt * dt/dy. dyₜ/dt is simply 0 when y is constant with respect to 0 but finding a useful definition for dt/dyₜ is harder. As yₜ does not vary dt/dyₜ is undefined or approaches a positive infinity. As such, dyₜ/dyₜ is best described as being undefined, I think. Alternatively it is not appropriate to use the chain rule when the denominator is a constant  value. However, some people may find it useful to patch in an ugly hack to our normal definition of the derivative and arbitrarily define dyₜ/dyₜ to be 1 or some other useful value for their purposes. I am not necessarily convinced such a patch would be useful but I would be open to the possibility.

Comment: Possibly wrong if the global time parameter t that you used is constant. Also what does "when y is constant with respect to 0" mean? I think the piece you are missing is that Leibnitz notation implicitly uses the quantity that appears in the denominator as a variable. So the worry about what happens when y is constant is a red herring. As others have pointed out you would have the same problem with dy/dx worrying about what happens when x is constant as well.